# Best way to estimate the size of a parking space (Python, OpenCV)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to determine the size of a parking space using a single camera.

For example, a parking space is on one side of the road between two vehicles and the camera is now looking from the side.

What is the best way to solve this? I have read that there is the Circle based Marker option where you detect a known length and use that to get the distortion out of the camera, then use the pixels and the deviation to determine the actual length.

What is the best way to solve this with Python or is there an alternative that is better?

is there any Github repo, for a guide?

Edit:
[image]
i don't have an actual image but i did a sketch for example. The Camera Position could be variable, so it's not a fixed position

Comment: show us a picture. -- this has nothing to do with yolo or AI. it's purely a vision/geometry problem.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz there is no actual Picture, but i drew a sketch for you. So do have an Idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us a real example image? Maybe try detecting the lines from the lot and calculate the width distortion?

Comment: @YvesDaoust for the known reference: can i use a defined square for example and put that on the road? But how do i estimate then die length of the Parkinglot?

Comment: @NoBlockhit at this time no, sorry. The lines of a parking lot, is not there everytime, so i want to solve the problem to calculate "free-floating" parking lots

Comment: Well without further information, this is mathematically impossible.

Comment: @NoBlockhit is there a way to do a "pre-meassurement", where you put down an Object, like a square for example for the known reference?

Comment: if you're asking how *Tesla* does it, they have *multiple cameras* (front-facing at least) and they have sophisticated AI. -- depth from monocular vision involves a neural network hallucinating data that isn't there (it **guess**timates the depth from recognizing objects in the scene and knowing how big they're supposed to be).

Comment: this question isn't a simple programming problem. you're asking to be given an entire lecture on computer vision because that's how much background you'd need to do this. that's **way out of scope** for questions on this site.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so for a single camera i can just do it with geometry?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz do you have an simple example for distance estimation to guide on?

Comment: Are you using image or video or both?

Comment: @Arthi you misunderstand. with a single camera and no other information, it is **impossible**. parking spaces on the side of the road are generally not adorned with any recognizable markers. you should give up this project. -- is this for a class assignment? then you should talk to your instructor.

Comment: @toyotaSupra currently a image, but there is the option to use a video as well

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so its an research topic for my thesis, it is not required to use recognizable markers from the road because every road has a different structure. If i use now my own marker for example a square, what i have defined and put that on the road for a period to calibrate the camera and get a kown reference, is it possible to estimate from that known size the length of a parkinglot by calculating the pixel and the calculated deviation?

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes the option is there, but not in the parkinglot especially. When I use a square with markers on each end and put it on the road, lets say on the end of the image, is it possible to estimate from that referenced object? So i saw some calibration methods with opencv using a chessboard, is that the functions what you mean?

Comment: @Arthi. You cannot used image. There is now ways to do this. Only video can do this. You  must known your car length and exacted length (empty space) between two parking. Depending in ur country.

Comment: @toyotaSupra: only a video ? What ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust sure, so to calibrate, i just need to meassure the square and the amounts per rows and the rows right? And after that i get the focal length or what do i get after calibrating with the chessboard?

Comment: If you can recognize the target region from taken image, and pre-calibrated camera (intrinsic and extrinsic) parameters are available, just calculate the length with the assumption "ground is plane".